# Install a new Ubuntu version over the frozen old version

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, login-screen, restore

My Ubuntu 15.04 has an issue of login loop and I can't fix the problem.  however,  this's not what I'm asking for. I decided to install a new version 16.04.

All what I need from my old frozen version is my pictures, videos in the Document folder!

How to not lose them!?

Comment: You could boot a live USB stick or live DVD, connect an external hard drive to your system and mount the external disk as well as your built in hard drive partition on which  /home resides. Then you can create a backup. (Pro tipp: create backups regularly, i.e. daily, even or especially when your system is doing fine.)

Comment: great tip to consider in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the Ubuntu 16.04 Live CD and a External HDD/Pendrive!

1. Download([64-bits](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso), [32-bits](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso)), Burn media and keep it.
2. If you know how big are your files, you can choose between an external HDD or Pendrive.
3. Boot from the Live CD.
4. Mount the partition in which Ubuntu 15.04 was installed:

   You can list every partition with: `fdisk -l`

   Create a mount point to HDD: `mkdir -p /media/hdd`

   Mount the desired partition with: `mount /dev/sdx /media/hdd`

   *sdx* can be *sda*, *sdb*, *sdc*... It depends on your system configuration.
5. Mount HDD/Pendrive.

   Create another mount point to pendrive/External HDD: mkdir -p /media/backup`

   Mount the backup device with: `mount /dev/sdx /media/backup`

   *sdx* can be *sda*, *sdb*, *sdc*... It depends on your system configuration.
6. Copy your HOME directory to your backup media(HDD/Pendrive).

   `cp -r /media/hdd/home /media/backup/`

Comment: How about using `TTY` terminal and `cp` my files to an external HDD before installing the new version?! will that work?!